# ssh-keygen create ssh key for linux user

Tags: linux, ssh-keys

Being a Sudo user, is it possible to create a SSH key for an user in the same Linux server? This Sudo user doesn't have a Switch user privilege.

I have a server where I Login as sudo user say 'admin'(doesn't have switch user privilege) and I have another user say 'user1'. I have a script in my server that should run as 'user1' which should call another script running in a remote host(remote host has a similar user named 'user1') during this process, the 'user1' needs an authorized key for remote host authentication. Since the sudo user 'admin' doesn't have the privilege to switch as 'user1' and generate the ssh keys, I'll have to generate the ssh keys for 'user1' as 'admin'

Comment: BD, the meaning of this question is not clear to me.  Is it possible to clarify what you're trying to do?  An example might well help.

Comment: For instance I can login as an user which has the sudo privilege and there is another user in the same server which is to be used for a task(Copying files across a remote server) and the authorized keys of this user needs to be added in the remote server. Being a sudo user, Is it possible to generate a key for this user?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /home/user1/.ssh/rsa_pub      Doesn't help me to create ssh keys for the 'user1'

Comment: If your question is "*as a user with sudo privileges, can I create a keypair, and put the public key into the `authorised_keys` file of another user, so that I'll be able to log in directly as them?*", then the answer is yes.

Comment: I am afraid that I went wrong with the details and I have updated my question in detaild for ref

Comment: why not connect as user1 and create the key as the user? login as user1, ssh-keygen as user1, ssh-copy-id user1@remote... or just copy the two files id_rsa id_rsa.pub to ~user1/.ssh/ and copy a good authorized_keys to user1@remote:~/.ssh/

Comment: @Dani_l But I don't have access to the user1 account.

Comment: If you can't copy files into user1's home dir, you can't do what you ask to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any sudo for this. 
Assuming you have sshd running with passwordAuth on server2 for user1, do the following from server1:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user1@server2
```

At this point, ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is installed on server2, and assuming pubkeyAuth is enabled on server2, you can try a ssh without pwd:

```
ssh user1@server2 ls
```

now, if you want to revert things (allow user1 from server2 to login in server1 with pubKey), do the following from user1 on server2:

```
scp user1@server1:.ssh/id_rsa .ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa
```

and on server1:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible without any problems. You can get your ssh private key into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file just as if you ssh-d into that account.

P.s.: BTW, there is no such thing as "sudo user". You are probably thinking on a user capable to get a rootshell with a sudo command, but it was not trivial to find out the proper meaning of your terminology. ALso there is no such thing as 'switch to user'. Do you think on some type of `su`-ing? Maybe you had to use everywhere known terminology.

Comment: can you get me the command that can help me in this?, I can check the same in my use case.

Comment: @BigData Of course: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html The only difference that you can do your initial login not by an ssh, but with your sudo command. You will be able to get a root shell with a local ssh after that (maybe `ssh root@localhost`).

Comment: With ref to the above link, is it possible to have an automatic login from host A / user b to Host B / user b?               Note: I don't have privilege to log on as user b at Host A and same time I don't have any access to 'host B'. Does it make clear?

Comment: @BigData With this link is it possible to ssh from every ssh account to every other without the need to type in a password. If you can't log in to these accounts, how can you use `sudo` on at least one of them?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how `sudo` is configured for your account. Often, it is restricted quite a lot to allow only a certain set of operations.

When in doubt, talk to your admin to help you out.

Some other approach: There is no requirement for the ssh key file to be at a specific place. You can create a set of keys wherever you like, add the public key to the remote users `authorized_keys` file and then use something like this:

```
sudo ssh -i /path/to/privkey user@host
```